# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'equipmentCheck' not found. 'equipmentCheck' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-templates

When I am trying to pull the code from github n my server where python version is 3.4 and Django version is 1.6 it shows the error for NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'equipmentCheck' not found. 'equipmentCheck' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
But the same code is running perfectly in pythonanywhere where I am using Python 3.6 and Django 1.11.4

**In urls.py**

```
url(r'^reservedequipment/check', views.equipmentCheck, 
name='equipmentCheck'),
```

**In views.py**

```
def equipmentCheck(request):
    pkk = request.GET.get('pkk')
    pk = request.GET.get('pk')
    start = request.GET.get('start')
    end = request.GET.get('end')

    d = DeviceUsage.objects.filter(equipment__pk=pk, start__lte=start, 
end__gte=start, status=1)
    if pkk:
        d.exclude(pk=pkk)
    result = {'ok': True}
    if d:
        result = {'ok': False}
    return JsonResponse(result)
```

**in template**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#check-form').on('submit', function(evt){
            console.log($('input[name="valid"]').val());
            if($('input[name="valid"]').val()==1){
                return true;
            }
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
            var elem=this;

            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'equipmentCheck' %}",
                data: {
                    pkk: "{{ booking.pk }}",
                    pk: $('input[name="equipment"]').val(),
                    start: $('input[name="start"]').val(),
                    end: $('input[name="end"]').val()
                },
                success: function(e){
                   if(!e.ok){
                       if(confirm('Your reservation time is overlapping with 
an existing reservation. Do you want to continue your reservation?')){
                           $('input[name="valid"]').val(1);
                           $(elem).submit();
                       }
                   }else{
                       $('input[name="valid"]').val(1);
                       $(elem).submit();
                   }
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: Enable DEBUG mode, write a wrong url at 127.0.0.1:8000 or where you are running Django 1.6 instance and check the available urls

Comment: You can't expect the same code to run on Django 1.6 and 1.11. There are many differences between them. Django 1.6 is insecure and out of date. If your code runs fine on pythonanywhere with Django 1.11, then you should use 1.11 on your server as well.